# How to spy on class instance without adding it to constructor?

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs

I'm testing my Node TypeScript application using Jest. I don't want to change my class at all, here's my class:

```js
export class UserRepository {
    async createUser(userData: User) {
        const prisma = new PrismaClient();

        await prisma.users.create({ data: user })
    }
}
```

I want to be able to check with Jest if `prisma.users.create` was called with `{data: user}`:

```js
  it('should call prisma', async () => {
    const prismaSpy = // I would add an instance of prisma and spy on it, but it would not spy on the instance created inside my repository
    const users = await userRepository.createUser();

    expect(prismaSpy).toBeCalledWith({data: users});
  });
```

This doesn't work, as it requires creating a new instance of `PrismaClient`, and inside my repository it will create a different one.
Since this is an integration test, I don't want to mock it. How can I spy on it?

Comment: As written, you can't. The client only exists during method execution, and is a locally scoped variable even then. Fundamentally you have to refactor to make it testable, so might as well do it properly and invert the dependency. But if this is an integration test you're not asking the right question; what should be tested is what gets stored, the behaviour, not the implementation detail of what method is called with what value.

Comment: Well, you see... We shouldn't refactor something in order to make it testable.
In my case, testing what's stored is not possible... I have a feature toggle that changes the behaviour completely, but the response is always the same.

Basically, if my toggle is true, it will call a different database and a different set of methods, but in the end, the response doesn't change... I want to test this feature toggle.

Comment: _"We shouldn't refactor something in order to make it testable"_ - that's not true. Testability is an important part of design that it's reasonable to refactor for. In cases where code was written without consideration for testability, you may _have_ to. And the _response_ may be the same, but you're saying the _behaviour_ isn't -  without context we can't say how, but that's what you should be asserting on.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you asked and on what you replied to @johrsharpe about the feature toggle: You should not test your feature toggle using integration tests, you should do it on a unit test, where you can mock your database and external components.

In simple terms: Your integration tests should make sure something happens and something is (or is not) returned, it shouldn't care (most of the time) on WHAT and HOW it does that, it should only care about what it did.

For example, integrations test should make sure, that, when you called **an endpoint**:

1. A new user was created and business logic was respected accordingly to your payload
2. Based on business logic, a set of information was retrieved and that matches your expected contract

On the other hand, unit tests should test a smaller part of your application, so instead of an endpoint, you're going to call a method, and that unit test should make sure:

1. Your method behaves the way you expect it to (like calling `X` if your toggle is true and `Y` if it's not)
2. Your method converts database payload to an expected contract
3. Your method calls `x`, `y` and `z` with `a`, `b` and `c` respectively

Those are, of course, examples and do not cover everything a unit and integration test should do.

And while you should not ADAPT your code to make your tests pass, you should certainly refactor your code so that it's testable.
What John said is that, you should refactor your application in order to be able to test it (like using DI), what you shouldn't do is adapt your code just so your failing tests starts to pass.

While it's not written in stone, unit tests should test the smallest fraction of your code, while integration tests should test, literally, how parts of your application integrates between them.

**@Edit:** When I mentioned that your integration test should call an endpoint, that's not necessarily true: Your integration test **might** call an endpoint, but it might also call a method and test integration with other components from there.
I figured I should make this clear so it's not confused with `e2e` testing.